# Hair and Eyelash Texture Problem

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm working on a model imported from SFM and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with the eyebrow, eyeball and hair texture. Can anyone help me how to properly set this up?

I'm experienced with animation, but not really that good when it comes to texturing and the other aspects of Blender. Thanks in advance.

[image: Texture in Cycles]

[image]

Comment: First thing to do would be to upload the blend file.
But, my best guess is that the "Alpha" texture is missing, and is instead pointed to the color node, or something similar. Alpha = transparency.

Comment: You may be right, but to me it looks more like a premultiply issue. In any case .blend + textures would be useful.

Comment: Okay. This isn't the exact file, but this is the base model that can be opened in Blender 2.8.

https://mega.nz/#!UtQVkK4a!Kv-k0pvzha047bJyk8ks5SHhNN_mdIqOyE2PEIlHrPY